# Send JSON object with POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a JSON object with POST

```
var user = {
    "first_name": first_name.value,
    "last_name": last_name.value,
    "age": age.value,
    "email": email.value
};
```

This is how I send the object :

```
var request;
var url = 'ajax_serverside_JSON.php';
var destination;

function ajax_call(src, jsonObj, dst, method) {

    this.src = src;
    destination = dst;
    this.objJSON = jsonObj;
    this.request = getXMLHttpRequest();
    this.request.onreadystatechange = getResponse;
    if (method == 'POST') {
        sendPostRequest(objJSON);
    }
    return;
}

function sendPostRequest(objJSON) {
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(objJSON));
    return;
}

function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera,Safari
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert('The browser doesn\'t support AJAX: ' + e);
        request = false;
    }
    return request;
}

function getResponse() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += request.response;
    }
}
```

Question: how do I read the object in the server side php ? What is the key o the sent json ?

`echo var_dump ( $_POST )`; shows

```
  array (size=0)
  empty
```

What is the problem?

**AFTER EDIT**

I changed my code to :

```
this.objJSON = jsonObj;
```

and

```
request.send("user=" + JSON.stringify(this.objJSON));
```

I try reading the JSON obj :

```
<?php
if (isset ( $_POST ['user'] )) {
    $obj = json_decode ( $_POST ['user'] );
    echo "isset";
} else {
    echo "is not set ";
    echo var_dump ( $_POST );
}
?>
```

...and still the same thing :

```
is not set

array (size=0)
  empty
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that PHP can automatically parse JSON into `$_POST` variables. You should put the JSON into the value of a normal POST variable:

```
request.send('data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(objJSON));
```

and use the default Content-Type. Then in PHP you can do:

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));
```

You also need to fix a Javascript variable, as explained in Niels Keurentjes's answer.

Comment: Idk why but `request.send('data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.objJSON)));` doesn't work... it gives me `Undefined index: data` same thing like before

Comment: I also check the POST tab with fire bug and I see that I have the entry " data=%7B%22first_name%22%3A%22das%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22dsa%22%2C%22age%22%3A%22dsadsa%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22dsadsa%22%7D"

Comment: That data looks correct. Did you get rid of the `setRequestHeader` call?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I just use jQuery and let it worry about the details.

Comment: string 'data={"first_name":"fdsfds","last_name":"fdsf","age":"dsfds","email":"fdsdfs"}' (length=78)

Answer (score 2):

Breaking your function down to its core 3 lines:

```
function ajax_call(src, jsonObj, dst, method) {
```

`jsonOBJ` is set in local scope as a variable.

```
this.objJSON = jsonObj;
```

`jsonOBJ` is copied to `this.objJSON`.

```
sendPostRequest(objJSON);
```

There is still no local variable `objJSON` since Javascript does not automatically consider `this` part of the local scope, hence null is sent, hence the empty `$_POST`.

Send `jsonOBJ` or `this.objJSON` instead and it'll work fine.

Comment: can you please take a look at "after edit" , maybe I didn't get something right. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
request.send("obj="+JSON.stringify(objJSON));
```

its a key value pair, I guess you are missing key.

Answer (score 2):

For your original Ajax request, you'll have to read the request body from `php://input` and decode then it.

```
<?php
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if (isset ( $post ['user'] )) {
    echo "isset";
} else {
    echo "is not set ";
    echo var_dump ( $post );
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to process json, placing json in an encoded form posted variable (get/post) just places more work on server side.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var user = {
                "first_name" : first_name.value,
                "last_name" : last_name.value,
                "age" : age.value,
                "email" : email.value
            };

$.customPOST = function(data,callback){
  $.post('your_php_script.php',data,callback,'json');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //suppose you have a button "myButton" to submit your data
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        $.customPOST(user,function(response){
         //on the server side you will have :
         //$_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], .....
         //server will return an OBJECT called "response"
         //in "index.php" you will need to use json_encode();
         //in order to return a response to the client
         //json_encode(); must have an array as argument
         //the array must be in the form : 'key' => 'value'
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to bring some clarity to the original question and perhaps clear up some potential confusion.  Rosca's question or confusion is that $_POST doesn't work in PHP when Posting a JSON object.  The reason is that the original request, although being done as a post is not being sent as a standard "forms" post request.  In a standard forms post, the request Content-Type should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and not "application/json".  In addition, the body of the post request should be a url-encoded query string and not a JSON encoded string.  They are formatted differently.  A query string might look like id=134626&type=car, where as a JSON encoded string would look like ["id"="134526","type":"car"].  Because the way the original request was sent, it's sending JSON object data and not URL encoded forms data.  So, PHP returns an error when you do something like $_POST["id"], because no forms data was sent.  The suggestions that others have offered is having PHP read the request body and process it as a JSON object. If you're sending the post request as a JSON object and processing it on the server side as a JSON object, that works perfectly fine!

The other thing you could do is to send the data as url encoded forms data content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), add the data as a valid query string, and process it on the server side as a standard forms post request.  If you do it that way, then yes, you can use $_POST["id"] in PHP to get the value of the "id" parameter.  Here's some javascript code that converts a JSON object to a query string:

```
function obj2qs(param
 var queryString = "";
 var sep = "";
 $.each(Object(params), function(key, value) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    queryString += sep + encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    sep = "&";
 });
 return queryString;
}
```

In the above, "params" is the json object that you want converted into a queryString.

Here's how to make those changes in Rosca's coding so that it is sent like a standard forms post:

```
function sendPostRequest(objJSON) {
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(obj2qs(objJSON));
}
```

The advantage of sending the request as a standard forms request is that you can easily create a simple html page for testing the page that performs the post operation.